# TypeError: validator is undefined error occur in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I have the following form:

[image]

But now once I click that Go to Next Section Button I'm not getting any response and I cannot go to the next page because I'm getting following error.

[image]

But this error occurs in Firefox only. Once I change to Chrome, this is working.

This is the sample HTML:

```
 <div class="section">
   ....
 </div>  

 <div class="section">
   ....
 </div> 
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Go to Next Section</button>
```

This is the script:

```
$('.btn-warning').click(function () {
    var container = $(this).closest('.section');
    var isValid = true;
    $.each(container.find('.form-control'), function () {
        $('form').validate().element($(this));
        if (!$(this).valid()) {
            isValid = false;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (isValid) {
        container.next('.section').show().find('input').first().focus();
        container.hide();
    } else {
        container.find('.error').text('please complete');
    }
});
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle?